# Error when taking snapshot of volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I want to create a sanpshot of a volumne but getting error

**ERROR: volume_id is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler**

Here is my yml file

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - local_action:
    module: ec2_snapshot
    volume_id: vol-3bca8f4d
    description: snapshot of volume
```

I am executig it as ansible-playbook

My ansible version is **1.6.5**

What is wrong in this yml file??

Answer (score 1):

When you use *local_action:*, you add the module name as a first parameter (without "module:") and continue with each parameter as if you where writing it the usual way.

```
- local_action: module param1=first param2=second
```

So in your case:

```
- local_action: ec2_snapshot volume_id=vol-3bca8f4d description="snapshot of volume"
```

Or, if you prefer multiline:

```
- local_action:
    ec2_snapshot 
    volume_id=vol-3bca8f4d
    description="snapshot of volume"
```

If you don't want to remember the difference between syntax, you could just do:

```
- ec2_snapshot: volume_id=vol-3bca8f4d description="snapshot of volume"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```